# Как использовать protected метод в чужого класса?

Tags: ооп, c#, методы

Добрый день! Не могу разобраться, как в своём наследующем классе использовать `protected` метод чужого базового класса.
Например, есть у меня класс `MyClass`, я наследую класс `YourClass` с методом
`protected void` **meth1()**

Я ничего не могу менять в чужом классе, геттеры и сеттеры не помогут, тогда как мне использовать этот метод, какие способы возможны? Спасибо.

Comment: Опишит подробно кто кого наследует. И из какого места требуется получить доступ к protected методу

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/protected/

Comment: Приведите код. Непонятно, где проблема: protected-методы из объектов порождённых классов всегда можно было использовать без проблем.

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае есть самый простой вариант - создать в своем классе public метод, который и будет осуществлять вызов protected метод у предка.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете без проблем использовать методы, помеченные модификатором доступа `protected`, в классах-наследниках. Для этого и был введен данный модификатор доступа, этим он и отличается от `private`

> Ключевое слово protected является
>   модификатором доступа к члену. Доступ
>   к члену с модификатором protected
>   возможен внутри класса и из
>   производных экземпляров класса.

Например:

```
public class YourClass 
{
    protected int YourMethod()
    {
    return 1;
    }
}

public class MyClass : YourClass 
{
    public MyClass ()
    {
    var a = YourMethod(); // вернет 1
    }
}
```

Подробнее почитать про `protected` [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bcd5672a.aspx)

Comment: Вопрос, как я понимаю, идет об использовании protected метода у класса наследника из другого класса. Как Вы правильно заметили, проблем в использовании данного метода у потомков не возникнет.

Comment: Перечитал вопрос и комментарий еще пару раз. До конца так и не осознал всю суть. Но скорее всего задача сведеться к получению интстанса наследника в нужном месте.